# Is there a term for matrices that are "close to singular"?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to explain that for a random square matrix $A$, it's possible that some entries of $A^{-1}$ will be very large (e.g. much larger than any entry of $A$). In my mind, I've generally associated this occurrence with $A$ being "close to singular", or "nearly rank deficient", but I'm curious if (a) this is always true (if $A$ is close to singular, $A^{-1}$ will have large entries), and (b) is there is a term that's preferred over "nearly singular" or "close to singular"?

Comment: See [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number).  A matrix that is "close to singular" is "ill-conditioned".

Comment: "Nearly singular" is an often-used term.  The product of a largest entry in $A$ as well as in $A^{-1}$ may more generally be replaced by $||A||\cdot ||A^{-1}||$ for various matrix norms.  It is of interest in numerical analysis in relating the accuracy of a solution of linear systems to the accuracy of the data.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks, I considered avoiding "ill-conditioned" since it tends to get wrapped up with a discussion of singular values, which I am trying to avoid, but it may be the best term here.

Comment: @hardmath thanks, wasn't aware of that result.

Comment: Your title asks about "a term" while the body expresses curiosity about "a more precise explanation or description".  It might improve the Question if you specified more about the subject matrix $A$ or what "scenario" you have in mind.  The notation $(A'*A)^{-1}$ seems a bit unrelated to the topic of nearly singular matrices, so perhaps more context is justified.

Comment: @hardmath It would have been clearer to just refer to some square matrix $A$, perhaps, but I was dealing with pseudo-inverses and that notation crept into my question. I've edited the question to be more general.

Comment: Okay.  The gist of my remark is that it is not so much that $A^{-1}$ is "much larger" than $A$, but rather that the product of "sizes" of both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ is large (relative to the working precision of our numerical representations).  After all, we can scale down $A^{-1}$ by a factor that then scales up $A$, with the effect that by scaling any pair $A$ and $A^{-1}$ we could revise them to have equally large "largest entries".